# Как добавить атрибут required в cotnact form 7 WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Мне обязательно нужен атрибут required у input в формах. Как добавить его в плагине cf7?

Comment: Ну так возьмите и добавьте атрибут используя jquery в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо указать звездочку (*) например

```
 [text* name class:required "Alex"]

 [submit "Send"]
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mghvi9    http://prntscr.com/mghvq2 Мне нужен именно атрибут

Comment: Изменил пример что бы именно атрибут.

Comment: Все равно не то, что мне нужно  http://prntscr.com/mgsjud . Дело в том, что у меня есть определенный скрипт и работает он только при наличии этого самого required . Вот к такому виду можно input привести?http://prntscr.com/mgskgg